# Windows Jenkins to connect with Linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, windows, docker, jenkins, ssh

How to connect Jenkins setup on windows machine to connect with a Linux server to create a docker image. SSH is not working. I am able to connect to the linux server through SSH from the machine but not from Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue where the openssh client wouldnt work with the jenkins ssh-agent plugin. To fix this I added the git path which is C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ to the system path environment variable just above the openssh one to use the Git ssh agent instead Once this is added it should be a case of restart your machine and it will work.